# Capturing Twitter Typeahead user interaction analytics (Piwik or Google Analytics)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, twitter-typeahead

I'm using Twitter Typeahead 0.9.3 and have it working pretty well displaying data from two different JSON files.

Now I want to obtain user engagement analytics from this application. Currently, when the user searches for something, results are filtered and suggested in real time and if the user clicks on one of the results, the search input box is populated with the value of the result that was clicked. (The search results aren't linked to another page, so normal search analytics don't work with what I'm trying to do).

The data that I want to capture can be found here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/v0.9.3/dist/typeahead.js#L980

I wanted to capture what the user searches for, and whatever value is clicked on to populate the input box.

From what I could find, I can achieve this by using 'Event Tracking', and I can potentially add `<input class="both" type="text" placeholder="Zehrs + Sobeys" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" oninput="ga(send, '_trackEvent', 'SEARCH', this.form.action, this.value]);` to my input but this doesn't seem to register anything in Google Analytics under Events.

I took a look at [Twitter Typeahead - Capturing events for Google analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086200/twitter-typeahead-capturing-events-for-google-analytics) but having a hard time understanding how I can integrate that into GA. I'm pretty green when it comes to JQuery but I'm learning by doing.

The universal analytics.js script I have in the header is:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-51227223-1', 'reetail.ca');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('send', '_trackEvent', 'SEARCH', 'action');
</script>`
```

Any and all help is appreciated :)